# ASP.NET Core multi-authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-identity

I have an ASP.NET Core web application for a Content Management System.
Therefore, the pages are dynamic and consist of dynamic areas. Each area has a class that manages its content.

Now, I need to enable users to authenticate through different systems (schema):

- Username and password (database)
- Windows Authentication
- Microsoft 365 (Azure AD, Microsoft Account)
- ADFS
- etc.

I have implemented multi-authentication in the following way:

```cs
builder.Services
    .AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddNegotiate()
    .AddWsFederation(
        options =>
        {
            var wsFederationSettings = builder.Configuration.GetSection(AppSettings.SectionNames.WsFederation).Get<WsFederationSettings>();
            options.MetadataAddress = wsFederationSettings.MetadataAddress;
            options.Wtrealm = wsFederationSettings.Wtrealm;
            options.CallbackPath = "/FederationResult";
        })
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration, configSectionName: "Authentication:AzureAD");

builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
```

I have then defined specific pages to "trigger" authentication.

So, for example:

To "trigger" Azure AD:

```cs
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public class AzureAdModel : PageModel
{ ... }
```

To "trigger" ADFS:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = WsFederationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public class WsFederationModel : PageModel
{ ... }
```

The authentication works for all schemes, but is this the correct way to implement multi-authentication?

In particular, I'm not sure if this is the correct way to use the cookie schema: `AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp` calls `AddCookie` using the `CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme`, so I cannot customize it.

But if I use another cookie schema for AzureAD authentication, then the users logged in with AzureAd results not authenticated in Identity (because the default schema is `CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme`).

Comment: "*Too many requests? Maybe I can split the question.*" Yes, questions on Stack Overflow should ask one thing. You currently ask about 4 different things.

Comment: Thank you @TylerH, I edit the question and created another one for Graph

Comment: For different scheme, you are use the right way, the authorize attribute parameter could specify the authentication schema. If one page should support multiple schema , you could put multiple authorize attribute or create a custom policy for it.

Comment: Thank you @BrandoZhang! I also do not understand how to use multiple authorize attribute, the original question was bigger, then I split it up with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77365962/asp-net-core-and-microsoft-graph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I also do not understand how to use multiple authorize attributes

For how to set multiple attributes, I suggest you could try below two ways.

One is directly set multiple attributes like below:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "CookieAuth")]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "JwtBearerAuth")]
public IActionResult Index()
```

Another is using policy like below：

```
// Authentication
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.Audience = "https://localhost:5000/";
            options.Authority = "https://localhost:5000/identity/";
        })
        .AddJwtBearer("AzureAD", options =>
        {
            options.Audience = "https://localhost:5000/";
            options.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/eb971100-7f436/";
        });

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("test", policy =>
    {
        policy.AuthenticationSchemes.Add(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        policy.AuthenticationSchemes.Add("AzureAD");
        policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser(); // Require an authenticated user
    });
});
```

Usage:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "test")]
public class HomeController : Controller
```