# ASP.NET Core and Microsoft Graph

Tags: asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, asp.net-identity

I've an ASP.NET Core web application.
Users can login with username and password or with Azure AD.

In a page with many info I want to show an info from Graph (e.g. Unread emails counter) only for Azure AD users. Other users simply can view the page, without the "Unread emails counter" info.

I don't understand how to make it work.
The problem is that Graph works only if I decorate the page with
`[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]`

but to allow other users to access the same page I cannot use that attribute.

Both

`[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = $"{OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme},{CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme}")]`

and

```cs
[AllowAnonymous]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
```

works for other users but do not works for Azure AD users because Graph throw exception

`InvalidOperationException: IDW10503: Cannot determine the cloud Instance. The provided authentication scheme was ''. Microsoft.Identity.Web inferred 'Cookies' as the authentication scheme. Available authentication schemes are 'Cookies,OpenIdConnect'.`

Here some code for your reference:

Authentication

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddNegotiate()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration, configSectionName: "Authentication:AzureAD");

builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseSession();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

The Razor Page

```cs
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public class GraphCMSModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly GraphLogic _graphLogic;

    public string Message { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public GraphCMSModel(GraphLogic graphLogic)
    {
        _graphLogic = graphLogic;
    }

    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
        if (AuthHelper.IsAzureAdAuthenticated)
        {
            var messages = await _graph.Me.MailFolders["Inbox"].Messages
                                  .Request()
                                  .Filter("isRead ne true")
                                  .GetAsync();
            Message = $"You have {messages.Count} unread messages";
        }
        else
        {
            Message = "No Graph for you";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Let's say if I were you, I might redesign my page and controller and api. That's because we have a view which containing 2 parts, one for all users and another for AAD users because we need to use graph api to query data for this part. So we might need to have 2 group of controllers and views which is designed for this 2 parts, and at first we need to design which kind of user is now signing in and then we route to the corresponding controller so that it would direct to the corresponding views. However, if we don't want to have 2 groups of controllers and views, we need to make the controllers

Comment: become compatible, so that we couldn't define a specific authentication scheme for the controller. Let's have an assumption with an mvc project, if we could have a controller which is allowed for authenticated users and when we return view, we display all other information except those only available for AAD users, and we also send a flag which define the current user type to the view too. In the view, we shall check the flag in the onload event then if it indicate that we need to query graph api, then send an ajax to an API which injected Graph client to get the data back and load them.

Comment: If all these unachievable, then shall we  have an opportunity that we do not use graph SDK but to use the basic access token, so that if we are signing in with AAD account in the app, we  should be able to generate an access token, so that whenever we have an access token, we could use it to call graph api to get data back. this is just my own humble opinion, and you might check if it's doable.

Comment: Thank you @TinyWang! I cannot redesign the webapp (it's far more complex than my sample) and would seem more like a workaround. Thank you for the "access token" solution. I think I will use this one if there are no other "standard" solutions.

Comment: Hi @TinyWang, I tried creating the Graph object without Authorize attribute but I've some other problems. I've asked in another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77398094/how-do-i-use-graphserviceclient-without-authorize-attribute

Comment: Sorry, in my humble opinion, creating graph object without authorize attribute is what I don't prefer to do. And the error `AADSTS500112` always means you didn't set a correct redirect url in Azure AD and in your project. the redirect url should be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way to tell GraphServiceClient what authentication schema to use using WithAuthenticationScheme method:

```cs
var messages = await graph.Me.MailFolders["Inbox"].Messages
    .Request()
    .WithAuthenticationScheme(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .Filter("isRead ne true")
    .GetAsync();
```